# PPAs will not install "sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found"

Tags: software-installation, repository, wine, ppa

I am trying to get the Linux distro "PIXEL" to install some PPAS for Wine, and I have run into a issue where it will not install because of the following error:

```
sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found
```

I am trying to install wine using the PPA `add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa` and I would like some assistance doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the package `software-properties-common`. You can do that with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

Comment: See: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44622/how-to-add-ppa-entries-manually-on-raspberry-pi